# How to count all words in few <p> with the same class by JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Something wrong with this code. When I manually have calculated all words it showed me 365, but when I use code bellow it returns me 450

```
function count(){

    var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName("text-sectors");

    var total_words = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++)
    {
        total_words += profile_values[i].innerHTML.trim().split(' ').length;
    }

    document.getElementById('word-sum').innerHTML = total_words;
}
count();
```

All content gets from backend so It is hard to provide proper HTML

**PS:**

```
total_words += profile_values[i].innerHTML.replace(/  */g, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
```

returns 375 words

```
total_words += profile_values[i].textContent.replace(/\\W+/, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
```

returns 391 words

Comment: how much `text-sector` is in you HTML code?

Comment: Put your text-sectors here.

Comment: Are there multiple spaces?

Comment: One thing to remember is `.innerHTML` will also include any HTML tags. If you just want to count words in the text maybe you want to use `.textContent` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your html file ?

Because you are using innerHtml, your method will also count any tags inside

tag. So any tag style, b, i will count as a word.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
total_words += profile_values[i].innerHTML.replace(/  */g, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
```

Comment: Does it counts dots or other symbols?

Comment: It counts each bloc of none-space characters as a 1.  So symbols inside a bloc like "alpha:beta" are not interpreted as separators.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the definition of a word.

Currently, the text `a. b  c` has 5 words by your definition.

I'd suggest to only see characters or numbers as word. A simple trick is to convert mutliple spaces to one:

```
  total_words += profile_values[i].textContent.replace(/\\W+/, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for me.

```
function count(){

    var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName("profile-value");

    var total_words = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++) {
      total_words += profile_values[i].innerText.trim().split(' ').length;
    }
    document.getElementById('word-count').innerHTML = total_words;
}
count();
```